# Android - how to place buttons and spinners with linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" 
    android:text="neshto">


    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Ok" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/size"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I cant post image with the result I'm looking for, but I want the two buttons Ok and Cancel to be below, the two spinners to stand almost right down to the text field. But I can't handle these layouts. Can somebody give me an idea? I've tried it so many times, but it's still not looking the way I want.

Comment: you want the buttons to be below `EditText` or below `Spinners`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as layout container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:text="neshto" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_below="@+id/size"
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:text="neshto" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/strut"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/strut"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/strut"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's okay, but I need Ok and Cancel to be in the bottom

Comment: @Jessica: I've updated the answer to put the buttons on bottom of the screen.